# What is "q" and "+" in the CSS style of the html body tag?

Tags: html, css

This is one of the top solutions for CSSBattle question #2. But I don't understand the "+" sign and "q" in this one line code.

```
<body bgcolor=62375 style=margin:0+50;border:dashed+53q#fdc57b;clip-path:inset(53q+0>
```

According to the research "q" means quotation mark and "+" is CSS adjacent selector, which doesn't make sense in this line of code,

Comment: read #4 here: https://cssbattle.dev/tips/

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS 'q' length, as an absolute length unit.
1q is equivalent to 1/40th of 1cm.

**EDIT**

Firstly, the inline style tag works without quotes because it is considered optional.

`border:dashed + 53q #fdc57b;` : We're having a dashed border, a + 53q and a color at the end. The `+ 53q' is a CSS selector.

The '+' sign in CSS is an adjacent sibling combinator. It combines two sequences of simple selectors having the same parent and the second one must come immediately after the first.

If you would view this yourself in a browser, you would notice that if you changed the value of `53` the dashed border would be changed in size. Or if you would remove it, the dashed border will have these small lines instead.

However i don't know why there is no closing brackets in the `clip-path:inset(53q+0`, maybe poorly written. Either way, it works.

Comment: How about the plus sign in that line?

Comment: Edited the post.

Comment: *The `+ 53q' is a CSS selector.* --> sorry but this is completey wrong ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just reading from the site. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp. Perhaps you have a better explanation?

Comment: a selector is used to select  an element and here we have the + sign inside the style tag so there is no selection

Answer (score -1):

`q` is a size unit, same as `px`
`+` is escaped space
You need to add some height to body to see the border, I guess it adds `body{height: 100vh}`

So basically this code adds 53px dashed border and then removes top and bottom 53px of the body, leaving left and right dashed border

```css
body {
  height: 100vh
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor=62375 style=margin:0+50;border:dashed+53q#fdc57b;clip-path:inset(53q+0>
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(98, 55, 80);
    margin: 0 50px;
    border: dashed 53q #fdc57b;
    clip-path: inset(53q 0);
}

body {
  height: 100vh
}
```

```html
<body>
```

Answer (score -2):

the + sign in css it can means two things:
1 - if used in the selector part,we called it combinator (adjacent seblings)
exemple: div+p{...}
2- if used inside the css rule the + signe replace a single space
exemple: selector{margin:50+50} equivalent of selector{margin:50 50},somme exceptions are to conceder. ex: selector{border:10px solid red} is not equivalent to selector{border:10px+solid+red}

Comment: "if used in the selector part" — Which it isn't here.

Comment: "the + signe replace a single space exemple" — I have never heard of that. Citation needed.

Comment: `{margin:50 50}` isn't valid CSS anyway. Non-zero lengths require units.